# How to embed interactive images or elements into a panoramic image viewer using THree.js and webGL?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, panoramas

How to embed more images and hyperlinks on a position in panoramic viewer as done in:

[THis link](http://www.montecarlovirtualtour.com/vuepanoramique/aerial-views/casino100m/#down)

[Panorado js viewer](http://www.panorado.com/en/PanoradoJsDemo.php).

The hyperlinks and overlays are embedded in this viewer. I tried to figure out how they are doing, However it is very hard to understand. Does anyone have nay idea of how to do that, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice extension toolkit called [THREEx](http://www.threejsgames.com/extensions/) with very handy tools.

There's a couple you may find interesting for what you intend to do:

- [threex.htmlmixer](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.htmlmixer) to integrate dom elements in webgl;
- [threex.domevents](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents) provides dom events in your scene;

With these tools you should be able to make your panorama images interactive very easily.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a panoramic viewer, I know how to do it, I am asking about embedding some buttons or hyperlinks to the panoramic image.

Comment: @NAYA sorry misunderstood your question, I'll update my answer